# Django, Managing User Data

Tags: django, file, accounts

I am using Django's user account management system to create accounts and login/ logout users.  Where I am having trouble is figuring out where and how to save user documents that my website creates for each user.

The purpose of my website is to properly format school documents for students.  They need to have access to these created documents on their account.

Right now, I am leaning towards using Amazon S3 web service to store the documents.  How can I 'attach' documents to the user and allow them to have access to them?  I thought about using the users email to find their documents but realized if they ever changed it, then they wouldn't be able to access them.  If that makes sense...

Please don't consider this question as opinion based but a "How-To" based.  Any answers are appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The way I would implement this is with a separate model which represents the document that a user should have access to. This model would contain:

- a ForeignKey to the settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL model
- a path to the file as found on S3 (either an entire URL, or just the prefix/key details could be built up to a full URL based on settings (for instance if you end up changing storage providers and migrating all data from S3 to, say, Rackspace cloud, it's easier to change settings than it is to trawl through potentially hundreds of thousands of records and update URLs in the database). If you use [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) they offer a FileField model field which semi-automates this for you, and also handles the uploading of the file itself to a designated S3 location. Also has the benefit of supporting other file storage backends as the need may desire.
- a document name/comment/title field of some description
- a created/last modified timestamp...just because that's how I roll.

If this model was called "Document", then you'd be able to access all documents belonging to a user via `user.document_set.all()` (I'd set the `related_name` on the `user` ForeignKey to `documents` to make this nicer into `user.documents.all()`). If the user changes their email address, that's fine, because we're using database's primary key for the user model instead.